# How to order list based on another list

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a list `List<T> ListT` of custom object type`<T>`.

Now there are two items in the list, one with `ID = 1089` and another with `ID = 1090`

Based on some logic, I will sort `ListT`using following way:

```
ListT = ListT.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Order.HasValue).ThenBy(x=>x.Order).ToList();
```

After the above query, `ListT` will now have `ID = 1090` be the first item and `ID = 1089` as second item.

Now I will retrieve another new list, `ListB` from database. The sample data would be as below:

[image]

My objective is to rearrange `ListB` so that the order of `ID` in `ListB` following the order of `ID` in `ListT`, and after that, rearrange `ListB` so that it would following the `Order` value in ascending order.

In the end, the expected result should be:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at IComparer and IComparable, I think that'll be the key to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
public class Foo {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }

    public Foo(int id, int? order) {
        ID = id;
        Order = order;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

    var ListT = new List<int> {1090,1089};
    var ListTOrder = ListT.Select((x, index) => new { Item = x, Index = index }).ToDictionary(x => x.Item, x => x.Index);

    List<Foo> ListB = new List<Foo> {
        new Foo(1089, 1),
        new Foo(1089, 3),
        new Foo(1089, 4),
        new Foo(1089, null),                
        new Foo(1090, 1),
        new Foo(1090, 3),
        new Foo(1090, 4)
    };

    ListB = ListB.OrderBy(x => ListTOrder[x.ID]).ThenBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
}
```

Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/th5fRD

Comment: Your piece of code doesn't work for me. The only difference I found is `ListT = new List<int>{1090,1089}`. `ListT` should be a type of `List<Foo>`. Can you please help update your answer?

Comment: ListT should be `List<Foo> ListT = new List<Foo> {new Foo(1089, null),new Foo(1090, null)};`